# Volume of Solid of Revolution

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid of revolution of the area enclosed by:

$x=2y$ and $x= y^2 - 3$

around the line $y=4$.

I understand that this is a function in terms of y, and graphing it out I realize that the rectangular strips need to be horizontal. Therefore, because they are parallel to the axis of revolution, the shell method would need to be used. However, I am getting stuck on how to set up the integral. I attempted this by saying:

$$2\pi\int_{-1}^3 (y+1)(y^2-3-2y) \,dy$$

I got the bounds by setting the two functions equal to one another and solving, and added 1 to the radius in the integral because the line $y=4$ is one above the top limit. I know I'm wrong but not totally sure what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David points out the radius should be $4-y$ because this is the distance between 4 and y. For example if y=0 then the radius would be 4-0 = 4.

There's another slight problem with the second part of your integral in that $y^2-3 -2y$ is negative. I know this because if you draw a picture, you get that the quadratic part lies to the left of the linear part, meaning that the $x=2y$ is greater than the $x=y^2-3$ so you should put $2y-(y^2-3)$ instead. Otherwise your setup is correct!

Answer (score 0):

The $y+1$ is the radius of the cylindrical shell.  It should be $4-y$ because this is the (positive) distance from $4$ to $y$.